# I am trying to use a for loop to draw different color lines in tkinter.

Tags: python

As can be seen I am a beginner, but have tried a couple of things eg # code

```
from tkinter import *
def main():
    canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=300, bg='white')
    canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)        
    #color=["red", "blue", "green"]
    color=(0, 255, 65535)
    x0,y0=150,150
    for i in range (1,4):

            #y=color(i-1)

            x1,y1=x0+i*10+10,y0-i*10+10
            canvas.create_line(0,0,x0,y0)
            canvas.create_line(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill=color(i))
            #canvas.create_line(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill="red")

main()
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: If you're trying to get the i-th element of `color`, try `color[i]` rather than `color(i)`.

Comment: Indexing in Python starts with 0. Since `colors` only has 3 elements the indexes are `0, 1, 2`. In your for loop you use `range(1,4)` which will evaluate to `[1,2,3]`. Thus `fill=color[i]` will throw an `IndexError` for the last iteration.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. Here it is modified slightly to spread the lines out.from tkinter import *
def main():
    canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=300, bg='white')
    canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)        
    color=["red", "blue", "green","yellow","magenta"]
    
    x0,y0=150,150
   
    for i in range (5):
            m=(-1)**i
            print(m)
            
            x1,y1=x0+(m)*i*20+20,y0-(m)*i*10
            print(x1,y1)
            print(color[i])
            canvas.create_line(0,0,x0,y0)
            canvas.create_line(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill=color[i])
           
            
main()

Answer (score -1):

```
from tkinter import *
def main():
    canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=300, bg='white')
    canvas.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)        
    color=["red", "blue", "green","yellow","magenta"]

    x0,y0=150,150

    for i in range (5):
            m=(-1)**i
            print(m)

            x1,y1=x0+(m)*i*20+20,y0-(m)*i*10
            print(x1,y1)
            print(color[i])
            canvas.create_line(0,0,x0,y0)
            canvas.create_line(x0,y0,x1,y1,fill=color[i])


main()
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?